# MaxItemsInObjectgraph in WCF

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I am having one problem.When I send request to server using WCF i get exception of

"Underlying connection closed
This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server "

I checked in wcf trace log and found that error was due to MaxItemsInObjectgraph exceeded more than 65536.But in my server side config file and in client side config file I have given MaxItemsInObjectgraph more than 65536 which is 2147483647.But still it gives error.Than I tried to give MaxItemsInObjectgraph value through code so wrote in service class as

```
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode =    AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    [ServiceBehavior(MaxItemsInObjectGraph = 2147483647)]
    public class CustomerAnalyzeService : ICustomerAnalyze
    {.....something
    }
```

but this is also not working.How should I solve this error.

Answer (score 1):

On service side config you should add MaxItemsInObjectGraph = 2147483647 to the ServiceBehavior and EndpointBehavior.